# Azure Functions IAsyncCollector fails to send Service Bus Messag Body

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-queues

I am facing issue with IAsyncCollector not sending the ServiceBusMessage Body property.

Here is my output definition:

```
[ServiceBus("queue2", Connection = "sbConnectionString")] IAsyncCollector<ServiceBusMessage> output
```

And here are lines of code used to produce ServiceBusMessage:

```
var m = new ServiceBusMessage();
m.Body = BinaryData.FromString(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myEvent));
m.CorrelationId = correlationId.ToString();
await output.AddAsync(m);
```

myEvent object is for sure not null, when debugging and exploring the final constructed message everything seems correct, but when I receive the message form the queue it has no body. I received message inside the code as well as using Azure Portal Service Bus explorer and both show empty body. CorrelationId is however propagated correctly. Please is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It look like you're using Azure Functions Isolated Worker. `IAsyncCollector` cannot be used. Instead, you need to return a primitive type such as string or byte[], or use a return type as I've described in [this post](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/functions-isolated-worker-sending-multiple-messages).

Comment: thank you Sean, but I am using class library project.

Comment: Not sure I understand your comment. Functions SDK what matters. How you develop and deploy your Function is irrelevant.

Comment: I am referring to documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide it is positioned as alternative to c# script and class library development. Project is running on .net core 3.1 and if I am not mistaken isolated process is supported only in .NET 5.

Comment: Then you should have stated so in the question  That's why I wrote "look like". Both are library classes. Nonetheless, in your case I suspect it's something that is off in your code. With in-process SDK `IAsyncCollector` works and you don't even need to flush. Perhaps share a repro in GitHub to see what's going on.

Comment: @Sean Feldman - thanks for your guidance. And what should we do if we don't need to queue another message? Just return null? Here's my question. Thanks so much. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73856111/isolated-process-azure-function-with-optional-servicebusoutput-return-value

Comment: @user11081980 answered. Hopefully that helps.