# Isolated process Azure Function with optional ServiceBusOutput return value

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus

I'm using an isolated process Azure Function with an output binding to Service Bus.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-output?tabs=isolated-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp) doesn't mention what to do in the case that there's no need to queue another message (e.g. if my processing code throws, I don't want want to keep queueing).

`IAsyncCollector` and `ICollector` are no longer supported in isolated process. So is returning `null` good enough to prevent it from queueing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no messages to enqueue, return an empty `IEnumerable`, not null. That way, Functions Worker SDK will [iterate over](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/functions-isolated-worker-sending-multiple-messages) no objects to turn into messages for dispatching. While `null` might work (I haven't validated it), it seems better to return an empty collection than a `null`.

In case your function is failing, let it fail. Don't try swallowing the exception and returning something you shouldn't have been returning, to begin with.